# Riverpods listen() not being called when its state changes from UserState object

Tags: flutter, dart, state, riverpod

I am listening to my Riverpods provider in my build method like so:

```
ref.listen<UserState>(userProvider, (UserState? prevState, UserState newState) {
      print("LISTEN CALLED");
}
```

**What I think should happen:**

Whenever I update my `UserState` object with a `.CopyWith()`, "LISTEN CALLED" should be printed.

**What actually happens:**

"LISTEN CALLED" is only printed once at the start of my program, and then even though the `UserState`'s properties change, the `listen()` is not called again.

---

Here is the call that updates my `UserState` (from a button):

```
onTap: () {
    ref.read(userProvider.notifier).logout();
}
```

This does a call to my database and device storage, and then executes this line of code:

```
return state = state.copyWith(
            newError: true, newLoading: false, newAccessToken: "", newLoggedIn: false);
```

This state is different than it is before the logout button is pressed (for example, `loggedIn` is true and `accessToken` has a value) - view code below to know what those are.

Here are the actual classes that use Riverpods, first up: `UserState`:

```
@immutable
class UserState {
  const UserState({
    this.error = false,
    this.accessToken = "",
    this.loading = true,
    this.loggedIn = false,
  });

  final bool error;
  final String accessToken;
  final bool loading;
  final bool loggedIn;

  UserState copyWith(
      {String? newAccessToken, bool? newError, bool? newLoading, bool? newLoggedIn}) {
    return UserState(
      error: newError ?? error,
      accessToken: newAccessToken ?? accessToken,
      loading: newLoading ?? loading,
      loggedIn: newLoggedIn ?? loggedIn,
    );
  }
}
```

Next, here's my `UserNotifier` class:

```
class UserNotifier extends StateNotifier<UserState> {
  UserNotifier() : super(const UserState());

  void logout() {
    // ... does lots of calls to database and device storage, then:
    return state =
        state.copyWith(newError: true, newLoading: false, newAccessToken: "", newLoggedIn: false);
  }
}
```

Finally, here is my provider:

```
final userProvider = StateNotifierProvider<UserNotifier, UserState>((ref) {
  return UserNotifier();
});
```

So, my problem is that everytime I call this `logout()` method (like from the button) my state CHANGES, but my `listen()` function from Riverpods is not called

Below code is NOT CALLED when my state changes through any method (like my `logout()` one), but I need it to:

```
ref.listen<UserState>(userProvider, (UserState? prevState, UserState newState) {
      print("LISTEN CALLED");
}
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the `return` in the `logout` method.

Try:

```
  void logout() {
    // ... does lots of calls to database and device storage, then:
    state =
        state.copyWith(newError: true, newLoading: false, newAccessToken: "", newLoggedIn: false);
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately, though thanks for the answer! I'm now not gonna do .listen() for my (authentication routing) code, instead I'm using .watch() which is worse - but should do the job if .listen() doesn't cooperate.

Comment: I have the same issue @Matthew Trent, any idea why is listen not working? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73015349/riverpod-listen-not-getting-called-after-statenotifier-changed

Comment: @rkris26 Had this issue a while ago now, but it ended up happening because the screen that the `listen` was on got disposed. So, I had to attach another `listen` to the screen that the app navigated to.

Comment: I have the listen on the home screen, where I list all of the restaurants, and the user can change his location on the profile screen (these are both bottomnavigation bar), so the change is happening on the profile screen, but I am listening to this on home, but that should not cause the issue. But the home won't get disposed, because I only fetch the home data once. If you have any codesnippet I would gladly take a look